# Collision2D not working in unity 2D even though everything is set equal to true and tags are set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

[Screenshot for unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ADY.png)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("escape") && gm.escape)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Volcano1");
        Debug.Log("ok");
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("megatron"))
    {
        conversation.SetActive(true);
        conversationBox.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("FirstBullet"))
    {
        megatronAnim.SetBool("shoot", false);
        megatronCanMove = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ScourgeEnemy"))
    {
        TakeDamage(10);
    }
}
```

In the top of the triggerEnter2D function it isn't colliding with escape. I have checked whether it is tagged escape and if escape is set equal to true and it is.

Comment: Did you set your colliders to is trigger = true? Also it should not be rigidbody kinematic.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your inspector window that shows the "Collider2D" component of your gameobject with tag "escape"?

Comment: alright done it is at the top and says screenshot for unity